# Spring Batch to Compare two files and find a matching records

Tags: java, spring-batch

Is there anyway we can compare two different files based on any specific column and get the values from one file using Spring Batch.

For example:

**File 1 Content:**

```
FirstName, LastName, Age
```

**File 2 Content:**

```
FirstName, LastName, Business
```

My requirement is something like based on FirstName and LastName i need to get the Business field. Basically i will iterate File 1 and search in File 2 to check for matching record.

Currently what i am doing is Index the File 2 using Apache Lucene and iterate the file 1 using Spring Batch and search in Lucene Index to get the matched documents.

I am looking something similar functionality using Spring Batch or any other frameworks?

Regards,
Shankar

Comment: Are your input files sorted on FirstName, Lastname? In that case you could create a custom ItemReader that iterates over both files simultaneously.

Comment: Actually thats not my file content.. i just put it for example.. our file contents are more of alphanumeric combinations and its not sorted...Thanks for your information. is it something we can do with Composite Item Reader?

Comment: No if the input files aren't sorted then I believe your current approach of writing one of the files to a datastore is a perfectly viable option.

Comment: @Jimmy Praet.. just wanted to how to write a custom reader that reads the files simultaneously.. i read Composite ItemReader will read more than one files simultaneously

Comment: @Jimmy Praet...If i get the files in the sorted order will it be faster than my current approach? if yes, how do i get two records simultaneously in the process method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work if you want to go the route of sorted input files:

```
public class MergingItemReader implements ItemStreamReader<MergedRecord> {

    private ItemStreamReader<RecordTypeA> readerA;
    private ItemStreamReader<RecordTypeB> readerB;

    @Override
    public MergedRecord read() throws Exception {
        RecordTypeA itemA = readerA.read();
        RecordTypeB itemB = readerB.read();
        Assert.isTrue(itemA.getKey().equals(itemB.getKey()), "Inconsistent data");
        return new MergedRecord(itemA, itemB);
    }

    @Override
    public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        readerA.open(executionContext);
        readerB.open(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext) throws ItemStreamException {
        readerA.update(executionContext);
        readerB.update(executionContext);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
        readerA.close();
        readerB.close();
    }

    public void setReaderA(ItemStreamReader<RecordTypeA> readerA) {
        this.readerA = readerA;
    }

    public void setReaderB(ItemStreamReader<RecordTypeB> readerB) {
        this.readerB = readerB;
    }

}
```

Regarding your other question about `CompositeItemReader`: there's no such thing. Maybe you are confusing it with `CompositeItemWriter`.