# In Spring Batch, how do we compare 2 flat files with different record layouts and throw error message when there is a inconsistency between them

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, flat-file, spring-batch-tasklet

Consider the below scenario, where I have 2 different CSV files with one common referential field. I want to read both the files and report an error if the file2 does not have the request-id similar to that of file1.

File1 is the primary file and the data in file 2 should always have a reference from file1.

Example:

**File1**:

**reqID, firstname, lastname**

111,John,miller

**File2**:

**reqID, custID, amount**

111, abc, 100

222, zxc, 200

333,qwe, 300

In the above case, I want to report a error that reqid 222 & 333 are not present in file1 and hence I cannot accept those records in file2 for further processing.

We cannot use MultiResourceItemReader as it does not support files with different record format.

I am looking for a solution using spring Batch framework.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Regards,
Gaurav

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Batch to Compare two files and find a matching records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28502712/spring-batch-to-compare-two-files-and-find-a-matching-records)

Answer (score 0):

You can read one file from the reader another file you can read from the processor and do comparison.

Comment: Could you please be a little bit more specific?